# Python Sort 2 different Size lists in same Order?

Tags: python, sorting

I wanna sort 2 different lenght list based on elementwise order.

I have 2 python lists which are sharing some elements like :

```
list_1 = [b,e,a,d,c]
list_2 = [b,a,c,k,l,f,d]
```

i know that using itertools's zip_longest i can sort 2 different sized list:

```
for k,j in zip_longest(list_1 ,list_2 ,fillvalue=None):
     print (k,j)
```

And this code gives me that :

```
b b
e a
a c
d k
c l
None f
None d
```

But is it possible that sort also same values in same order like:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,None,None,None]
[a,b,c,d,None,f,k,l]
```

or like that format :

```
a,a
b,b
c,c
d,d
e,None
None,f
None,k
None,l
```

Thanks A Lot !

Comment: Why is there a `None` between `'d'` and `'f'` in the output?

Comment: Please use functional example code. Your list elements are not strings.

Comment: @Austin i guess because 'e' is before 'f and after 'd' alphabetically

Comment: @Austin Because there is no element corresponding to "e". Thanks alot for comments.

Comment: @Jab i just tried to explain using abstaction . I just need to understand algorithm or idea behind the solution, but u're right next time i'll be careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `set` to get all elements in both lists then replace missing values with None in a list comprehension:

```
list_1 = ['b','e','a','d','c']
list_2 = ['b','a','c','k','l','f','d']
combined = sorted(set(list_1 + list_2))

new_list_1 = [c if c in list_1 else None for c in combined]
new_list_2 = [c if c in list_2 else None for c in combined]

print(new_list_1, new_list_2, sep='\n')
```

---

Results:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', None, None, None]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', None, 'f', 'k', 'l']
```